# Randomized selection complexity

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, selection-sort

after analyzing the algorithm complexity I have a few questions:

For the best case complexity -  the recurrence relation is `T(n) = T(n/2) + dn` which implies that the complexity is `Θ(n)`.

So by the master theory I can clearly see why this is true , but when I draw the algorithm recursive calls as a tree I don't fully understand the final result. (It seems like I have one branch in height of log(n) which in each level I operate a partition O(n) - so it suppose to be `nlog(n)` .
(just for memorizing - this is very similar to the best case of mergeSort algorithem , but here we ignore the unwanted sub-array after partition).

Thanks!

Comment: N+N/2+N/4+N/8+...=2N even though there are Log(N) terms.

Comment: Can u please write the full equation using the sigma notation?

Answer (score 2):

It is as Yves Daoust wrote. Image it with real numbers, i.e. n=1024

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + dn
T(1024) = T(512) + 1024
T(512) = T(256) + 512
....
T(2) = T(1) +  2 -> this would be the last operation
```

Therefore you get `1024+512+256+...+1 <= 2048`, which is `2n`

You must think about that `dn` is as big as `n`, but in recurrence relation the `n` is not global variable, it is local variable based on method you call.

So there is `log(n)` calls but they do not take `n`-time everyone, they take less and less time.